# Pulley problem: I included the here the the picture of what i already tried doing

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, rotational-dynamics, string

[Pulley problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzO2n.png)

[image: what i have tried doing]

> Problem: Find the tensions in the two cords and the acceleration of the blocks if friction is negligible. The pulleys are massless and frictionless, m1=200g, m2=500g and m3=400g.

I am not sure if the acceleration I got is correct and I don't know where to start to solve for the tensions.

Comment: Where is the text of the problem?

Comment: Your problem is with the acceleration of mass m1.  It is not the same as masses m2 and m3.

Comment: Let's see your individual force balances on m1, m2, m3, and the pulley.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your coordinate system around the pulley as indicated by the curved arrow on the sketch.  Write a separate force equation for each mass.  Note that $a_2$  = $a_3$,  $a_1$ = 2$a_2$ and $T_1$ acts twice on $m_2$.